# Using Excel to create Visio ER Diagram

Tags: excel, database, entity-relationship, visio

I have an excel table that I want to use to generate a Visio diagram of my database. I don't have the database on hand so I can't just point Visio to it. I only have the excel file that lists the `table, field and field type`. For example

[image]

I want to use something like this to create an ER diagram in Visio but I can't figure out how to import the data into Visio in this current format.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Data --> Link Data to Shapes --> Microsoft Excel Workbook....

Answer (score -1):

Try using the "Basic Flowchart - Data Visualizer" template in Visio (this might only be available in the Online Plan 2).  LinkedIn Learning has a class called "What is Data Visualizer?" from the course "Excel and Visio: Generating Diagrams Automatically," and it explains what information is required to create a diagram in Visio from Excel information.